# Ideas with loops in php for creating css/html element

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, loops

I need to put a whole bunch (hundreds) of graphic element in a webpage. I would like to use html and css, but to use PHP script (using loops) so that I don't have to do it manually.
I can create a table like this (for example, in comma delimited), I can import to Mysql:

```
Element,Width,Height,x-position,y-position,image
1,24,26 30,40,Photo1.jpg
2,46,34,50,78,Photo2.jpg
```

A bunch more data points.

The actual code I would  would need to generate is (for example):

```
#element1{
height: 26px;
width: 24px;
top: 40px;
right: 30px;
background-image: url(Photo1.jpg);
}
```

Of course there will be a bunch of these, with the values being read from the table.

I am new to programming. Thanks in advance for all your advise and ideas.

Comment: Here are the functions you'll need to use: explode, foreach, echo, file_get_contents. You can find them all at http://php.net. If you give it a try and post the code you're stuck with I can help.

Comment: Honestly, I am just learning programming, at this point using mostly what offered with Dreamweaver; connect to Database, read-write, forms etc. To handle this, without anything else, I would do a "mail-merge" to create the text/code in Word/Excel, then cut and paste the code directly.

Answer (score 2):

It's going to be slow for the page to show. Directly from the CSV and using inline css instead of one set of rules per element

PHP

```
$csv=file_get_contents('thecsvfile.csv');
$images=explode("\n", $csv);
unset($csv); // don't want this in memory any more

foreach ($images as $image) {
    $bits=explode(',', $image);
    # 0:Element, 1:Width, 2:Height, 3:x-position, 4:y-position, 5:image
    echo '<img src="'. $bits[5] .'" style="position:absolute; width:' 
        . $bits[1] .'px; height:' . $bits[2] .'px; left:'
        . $bits[3] .'px; top: ' . $bits[4] .'px;" alt="' . $bits[0] .'" />';
}
```

Edited to use img tag

Comment: Thanks so much. In this case no real reason for having the image with css background property. Is the performance better if placing it directly on the div instead?

Comment: The amount of HTML is hardly any different and the browser has to load the images anyway so no there's no difference. Code updated to use an img tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

it's easier to style them  inline e.g.:
`<div style="height:40px;width:60px;..."></div>`

It's better then creating separate css rules for each element by id

Comment: normally I would disagree, inline css is ugly, but in this instance that's a good call.